# D3: How to pull JSON from Github API

Tags: d3.js, github, github-pages, github-api

I am trying to get visualisations using github API data but cant seem to get it pulled. From the documentation I thought the following line would work but nothing prints to the console when I run it. Am I missing something

```
d3.json("https://api.github.com/search/users?q=ronanmacf", 
function(data) {
console.log(data[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but, in this case, the server response is an object, not an array so you get `undefined` with `console.log(data[0])`. If you change it like this `console.log(data)` you will see the github user data in the console. Run the code snippet below:

```js
d3.json("https://api.github.com/search/users?q=ronanmacf", 
function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `jQuery` also we put `console.log(data)` instead of `console.log(data[0])`

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=ronanmacf", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```